# Calculating data based on before, between, and after dates

Tags: excel

So I am having a hard time even conceptualizing how to do this and am hoping for some guidance. I have a worksheet where users will input a start date and an end date into lets say B2 & C2. The worksheet imports a list of transactions (purchase and use of a product) and I want to be able to calculate how much of the product we have before the date in B2, then how much we used between B2 and C2 and how much we then have left at the end of day on C2.

I think it will be easy enough to set a tally in a column so the value itself is easy enough to grab, but navigating values before and inbetween dates is where I am getting stuck. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Sounds like SUMIFS would be what you want.

Comment: This is super rough but since this is a dynamic range of data, I will run code to convert to a table. But this is the super rough version of what I interpret that to be:

SumIf ImportTable Column Date is between A1 & B1, else sumif ImportTable Column Date is less than B1+1

I cannot think of what to add to get it to look from the date column to the total column. Am I close?

Comment: Ok this might make more sense. Is this correct I could just split it into two or three cells:
SumIf(ImportTable[Date], < A1, ImportTable[Total]) 
SumIf(ImportTable[Date], <= B1, ImportTable[Total])
SumIf(ImportTable[Date], >= A1 & ImportTable[Date], <= B2, ImportTable[Total])